# Calling Validator gives NoProviderFoundException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openapi, bean-validation

**I have the following dependencies defined in my gradle build (Spring Boot version is 2.7.7)**

```
// Spring Boot
implementation group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-actuator"
implementation group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-validation"
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure'
implementation group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-web"
implementation group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-mail"


// Swagger/OpenAPI CodeGen
implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.6.14'
implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-common', version: '1.6.14'
implementation group: "org.openapitools", name: "jackson-databind-nullable", version: "0.2.4"

compileOnly group: "org.projectlombok", name: "lombok"

annotationProcessor group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-configuration-processor"

// Utils
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0'`
```

**In my Service I have the following implementation**

```
@Override
public List<MyObjectValue> getApplicationDetailFromSearch(@Valid MySearchModel mySearchModel) {

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<MySearchModel>> violations = validator.validate(mySearchModel);

    if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
    }
```

`MySearchModel` is a record Annotated with `@MySearch` with the corresponding `MySearchValidator` implementation

The Result, when I call the validator is

```
javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Jakarta Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:291) ~[jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:103) ~[jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at
```

Comment: I also tried an approach without retreiving the Validator to programattically execute it but puting the Annotation directly on the Parameter with the effect that nothing happens.

Comment: What I also tried is to define a bean in my Application but thtis now gives me the error "The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found

Comment: Assuming this is in an controller remove the validation from the method, you already have `@Valid` which triggers the validation. If you want to access the violations add `BindingResult` as an additional method parameter. If this is **not** in a controller you need an additional `@Validated` on the class to trigger validation for method parameters.

Comment: I am coming from an RestController into a Service. Even if I put @Valid on the Parameter of the Servioce method nothing happens. May there probalbly an issue using Spring boot togehter with openAPI Generator, i.e. conflicting dependencies?

Comment: The Service has Validate Annotation and the Method Parameters have Valid Annotation and nothing happens. I foloowed this approach https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/

Comment: Generally this is more of a dependency problem as in not including a validator implementation or messing around with unsupported versions. Another commen thing is that auto configuration in Spring Boot is disabled due to adding `@Configuration` classes trying to enable features that are already enabled by default (and thus disabling auto-configuration for certain parts). In short adding an `@Validated` to the class should make it work. If it doesn't you are probably having 1 of the aforementioned issues. Add more information (full build, configuration etc.) if we need to look further.